# CruiseControl.Net Web Dashboard not displaying results

Tags: msbuild, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Having problems displaying the results in CruiseControl.net web dashboard.

I've built a config file which kicks off a build of the project.  It then runs `nunit` over my tests, they execute and finish just fine (I can open the log and see the results there).  The `ccnet` logs show that the log files were successfully merged.  However, try as I might, I can't get it to appear in the web dashboard.  It just gives the frustrating:

```
BUILD FAILED
Project:    GroundControlTests
Date of build:  2011-01-07 17:16:36
Running time:   00:00:58
Integration Request:    mmayo triggered a build (ForceBuild) from PC0098
Projects built with no warnings at all :-)
Modifications since last build (0)
```

message, despite failing.

I suspect it has something to do with the xsl transforms, but have tried just about everything I can think of.

Certainly if I click View Build log, it shows, but the main report doesn't show passes and fails :(

My config files are below, any suggestions appreciated!

**---nant.build---**

```
<project name="GroundControl" default="cleanNunit" basedir=".">
  <description>Cleanup tasks</description>
  <target name="cleanNunit"
         description="removes nunit log file">
    <delete file="${CCNetArtifactDirectory}\nunit-results.xml"
          failonerror="true" />
  </target>
</project>
```

**-----ccnet.config-------**

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

    <project name="GroundControlTests">
      <workingDirectory>C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot</workingDirectory>
      <artifactDirectory>C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot</artifactDirectory>
    <prebuild>
      <nant>
        <executable>C:\Nant\bin\nant.exe
        </executable>
        <baseDirectory>C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot</baseDirectory>
        <nologo>false</nologo>
        <buildFile>nant.build</buildFile>
        <targetList>
          <target>cleanNunit</target>
        </targetList>
      </nant>
    </prebuild>

    <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
            </executable>
            <workingDirectory>C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot
            </workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>GroundControlReboot.sln</projectFile >
            <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger 
            /v:quiet 
            /noconlog 
            /p:Configuration=Debug
            /p:ReferencePath="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"
            /p:AdditionalReferencePath="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"
            </buildArgs>
            <targets>ReBuild</targets >
            <timeout>180</timeout >
<!--            <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCNet.dll</logger>-->

        </msbuild>
        <exec>
            <executable>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe
            </executable >
            <buildArgs>/xml:C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot\nunit-results.xml
        C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot\GroundControlReboot\bin\Debug\GroundControlReboot.dll
      </buildArgs>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>180</buildTimeoutSeconds>
        </exec>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
      <merge>
        <files>
          <file>
        C:\Source\Wholesale\Code.EventControl.TestingFramework\GroundControlReboot\*-results.xml
      </file>
        </files>
      </merge>
      <xmllogger />
      <statistics />
      <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
        cleanUpValue="20" />
    </publishers>

    </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

**-----dashboard.config-------**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dashboard>
  <remoteServices>
    <servers>
      <server name="local" url="tcp://localhost:21234/CruiseManager.rem" allowForceBuild="true" allowStartStopBuild="true" backwardsCompatible="false" />
    </servers>
  </remoteServices>
  <plugins>
    <farmPlugins>
      <farmReportFarmPlugin />
      <cctrayDownloadPlugin />
      <administrationPlugin password="" />
    </farmPlugins>
    <serverPlugins>
      <serverReportServerPlugin />
    </serverPlugins>
    <projectPlugins>
      <projectReportProjectPlugin />
      <viewProjectStatusPlugin />
      <latestBuildReportProjectPlugin />
      <viewAllBuildsProjectPlugin />
    </projectPlugins>
    <buildPlugins>
      <buildReportBuildPlugin>
        <xslFileNames>
        <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\msbuild2ccnet.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
        <xslFile>xsl\nant.xsl</xslFile>     
        <xslFile>xsl\tests.xsl</xslFile>
        </xslFileNames>
      </buildReportBuildPlugin>
      <buildLogBuildPlugin />
    </buildPlugins>
    <securityPlugins>
      <simpleSecurity />
    </securityPlugins>
  </plugins>
</dashboard>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I deployed the nunit package from the dashboard admin it generated three things:

Under buildReportBuildPlugin it added xsl\unittests.xsl. This is for the build summary page.
It also generated two items for the sidebar to see nunit details (xsl\tests.xsl) and nunit timings (xsl\timings.xsl). It looks like you have the nunit details xsl file defined for the build summary page which may be why you don't see anything. If you use xsl\unittests.xsl instead (and reload the dashboard so it actually reads the updated file) that may work. Another option is to just deploy the nunit package from the web dashboard administration page which will update the dashboard.config file for you.

```
<buildPlugins>
  <buildReportBuildPlugin>
    <xslFileNames>
      <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\unittests.xsl</xslFile>
    </xslFileNames>
  </buildReportBuildPlugin>
  <buildLogBuildPlugin />
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NAnt Output" actionName="NAntOutputBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\NAnt.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NAnt Timings" actionName="NAntTimingsBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\NAntTiming.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NUnit Details" actionName="NUnitDetailsBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\tests.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NUnit Timings" actionName="NUnitTimingsBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\timing.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
</buildPlugins>
```

Comment: Tried putting in those xsl files, but to no avail...and the documentation recommends against using the nunut package...any other theories?  Much appreciated.

Comment: No, wait, I hadn't tried the deploying of the nunit from the dashboard.  Lo and behold, it worked perfectly! Thank you, good man!